# Can't get Kivy code to work

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to run a simple hello world program using Kivy. I have the correct version (1.8) installed on my Mac, but I am getting an error message and the window does not open up.

```
 from kivy.app import App
 from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
 def build(self):
    return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()

$ python hello_world.py 
[INFO              ] Kivy v1.8.0
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/d/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-01-13_4.txt
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 157 symbols loaded
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_imageio, img_tex, img_dds, img_pil,     img_gif (img_pygame ignored)
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600s
[DEBUG             ] [Text        ] Ignored <pygame> (import error)
[DEBUG             ] [Text        ] Ignored <sdlttf> (import error)
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_pygame', 'text_sdlttf'] ignored)
[DEBUG             ] [App         ] Loading kv <./test.kv>
[DEBUG             ] [App         ] kv <./test.kv> not found
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Ignored <pygame> (import error)
[WARNING           ] [WinPygame   ] SDL wrapper failed to import!
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Ignored <sdl> (import error)
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Ignored <x11> (import error)
[CRITICAL          ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
Exception SystemExit: 1 in 'kivy.properties.dpi2px' ignored
[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: Looks like it has some dependencies that you haven't installed.

Comment: Those errors are kivy going through all the possible window providers and finding that none are availble. Do you have pygame installed? Or are you using the kivy package from the website?

Answer (score 0):

According to lines

```
[DEBUG             ] [Text        ] Ignored <pygame> (import error)
[DEBUG             ] [Text        ] Ignored <sdlttf> (import error)
```

your dependencies for Kivy may be improperly installed or out of date, just as Mark Ransom has said. Try updating Kivy's dependencies. [This thread](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3002) over at the Github Kivy forum has gone into great detail on the issue, though it is on Ubuntu instead of Mac OSX, and several users have reported that updating the Kivy depencies resolves the issue.